# Dynamically ADDING and REMOVING Components in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The current official docs only shows how to dynamically **change** components **within** an `<ng-template>` tag. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

What I want to achieve is, let's say I have 3 components: `header`, `section`, and `footer` with the following selectors:

```
<app-header>
<app-section>
<app-footer>
```

And then there are 6 buttons that will add or remove each component: `Add Header`, `Add Section`, and `Add Footer`

and when I click `Add Header`, the page will add `<app-header>` to the page that renders it, so the page will contain:

```
<app-header>
```

And then if I click `Add Section` twice, the page will now contain:

```
<app-header>
<app-section>
<app-section>
```

And if I click `Add Footer`, the page will now contain all these components:

```
<app-header>
<app-section>
<app-section>
<app-footer>
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Angular? Note that `ngFor` is not the solution I'm looking for, as it only allows to add the same components, not different components to a page.

EDIT: `ngIf` and `ngFor` is not the solution I'm looking for as the templates are already predetermined. What I am looking for is something like a stack of `component`s or an `array` of `component`s where we can add, remove, and change any index of the `array` easily.

EDIT 2: To make it more clear, let's have another example of why `ngFor` does not work. Let's say we have the following components:

```
<app-header>
<app-introduction>
<app-camera>
<app-editor>
<app-footer>
```

Now here comes a new component, `<app-description>`, which the user wants to insert in between  and `<app-editor>`. `ngFor` works only if there is one same component that I want to loop over and over. But for different components, `ngFor` fails here.

Comment: If they are known, as in your example, you could use *ngIf on the header and footer and *ngFor on the sections.

Comment: @DeborahK ngIf and ngFor is not the solution I'm looking for as the templates are already predetermined. What I am looking for is something like a stack of components or an array of components where we can add, remove, and change any index of the array easily.

Comment: This might also help if you want to add different kinds of components https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks! This might be especially useful as I get to know ngComponentOutlet

Comment: `ngComponentOutlet` is still lacking some basic features. There is a pull request to address these since a long time but it wasn't yet merged AFAIK. So reading and passing values from/to dynamically added components doesn't work well.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if anyone comes to this in the future looking for information about how to dynamically add components, the first step is to be *really* sure you actually need dynamic components.  If you have a (relatively) small list of components that might be nested in different ways, you should seriously consider creating a data structure that represents your nested components, and a series of components that can render each other as children, using a combination of `ngFor` and `ngSwitch`.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can be done by creating components dynamically using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` and then injecting them into a `ViewContainerRef`. One way to do this dynamically is by passing the class of the component as an argument of your function that will create and inject the component.

See example below:

```
import {
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver, Type,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

// Example component (can be any component e.g. app-header app-section)
import { DraggableComponent } from './components/draggable/draggable.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <!-- Pass the component class as an argument to add and remove based on the component class -->
    <button (click)="addComponent(draggableComponentClass)">Add</button>
    <button (click)="removeComponent(draggableComponentClass)">Remove</button>

    <div>
      <!-- Use ng-template to ensure that the generated components end up in the right place -->
      <ng-template #container>

      </ng-template>
    </div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

  // Keep track of list of generated components for removal purposes
  components = [];

  // Expose class so that it can be used in the template
  draggableComponentClass = DraggableComponent;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  addComponent(componentClass: Type<any>) {
    // Create component dynamically inside the ng-template
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentClass);
    const component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

    // Push the component so that we can keep track of which components are created
    this.components.push(component);
  }

  removeComponent(componentClass: Type<any>) {
    // Find the component
    const component = this.components.find((component) => component.instance instanceof componentClass);
    const componentIndex = this.components.indexOf(component);

    if (componentIndex !== -1) {
      // Remove component from both view and array
      this.container.remove(this.container.indexOf(component));
      this.components.splice(componentIndex, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. If you want to make it easier to remove the components later on, you can keep track of them in a local variable, see `this.components`. Alternatively you can loop over all the elements inside the `ViewContainerRef`.
2. You have to register your component as an entry component. In your module definition register your component as an entryComponent (`entryComponents: [DraggableComponent]`).

Running example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mrXtE1ICw5yeIUke7wl5

For more information:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Thanks! This might be the solution I am looking for but I haven't tried it out yet. Would you be so kind as to provide a Plunker?

Comment: I have added a plunker to the answer. Please see [https://plnkr.co/edit/mrXtE1ICw5yeIUke7wl5](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrXtE1ICw5yeIUke7wl5). Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited the Plunker to include different components (foo and bar) and it works! Thank you very much! https://plnkr.co/edit/tMR2ahkb5VRpWCIh2Jvb?p=preview

Comment: Excellent example and code. I was searching for exactly this. I would just suggest editing this "const component = this.components.find…" to "const component = this.components.reverse().find…" in order to remove last inserted component. Or add id's to them to track specific ones.

Comment: There is also a tutorial about this here: https://courses.ultimateangular.com/courses/angular-pro/lectures/2170084

Comment: Hi @AshBelmokadem thanks so much for this answer.  Do you, or anyone, know how to update this example to support bindings? e.g. if I wanted `DraggableComponent` to bind to the `let` property on the `ng-template`, how would you do that?  If you were to write it manually it would look like

`<ng-template #ref let-item>
<my-component [myBinding]=item></my-component>
</ng-template>`

Comment: `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated.

Answer (score 59):

### Angular v13 or above - simple way to add dynamic components to DOM

`parent.component.html`

```
<ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
```

`parent.component.ts`

```
@ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcr!: ViewContainerRef;
ref!: ComponentRef<YourChildComponent>

addChild() {
  this.ref = this.vcr.createComponent(YourChildComponent)
}

removeChild() {
  const index = this.vcr.indexOf(this.ref.hostView)
  if (index != -1) this.vcr.remove(index)
}
```

### Angular v12 or below

I have created a demo to show the dynamic add and remove process.
The parent component creates the child components dynamically and removes them.

#### [Click for demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-or-remove-dynamic-component)

**Parent Component**

```
// .ts
export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  VCR: ViewContainerRef;

  child_unique_key: number = 0;
  componentsReferences = Array<ComponentRef<ChildComponent>>()

  constructor(private CFR: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  createComponent() {
    let componentFactory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);

    let childComponentRef = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);

    let childComponent = childComponentRef.instance;
    childComponent.unique_key = ++this.child_unique_key;
    childComponent.parentRef = this;

    // add reference for newly created component
    this.componentsReferences.push(childComponentRef);
  }

  remove(key: number) {
    if (this.VCR.length < 1) return;

    let componentRef = this.componentsReferences.filter(
      x => x.instance.unique_key == key
    )[0];

    let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef as any);

    // removing component from container
    this.VCR.remove(vcrIndex);

    // removing component from the list
    this.componentsReferences = this.componentsReferences.filter(
      x => x.instance.unique_key !== key
    );
  }
}

// .html
<button type="button" (click)="createComponent()">
    I am Parent, Create Child
</button>
<div>
    <ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
</div>
```

**Child Component**

```
// .ts
export class ChildComponent {

  public unique_key: number;
  public parentRef: ParentComponent;

  constructor() {
  }

  remove_me() {
    console.log(this.unique_key)
    this.parentRef.remove(this.unique_key)
  }
}

// .html
<button (click)="remove_me()">I am a Child {{unique_key}}, click to Remove</button>
```

Comment: You could replace `.filter(x => x.instance.index == index)[0]` by `.find(...)`

Comment: Yeah, you're right but that were old days buddy when I wrote this ;)

Comment: This solution not work with Ivy=enabled . See stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tdqan6 . It is fails on removing the component

Comment: I made it work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k6nqph  . I changed in remove method let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef) with let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef.hostView);

Comment: I would use `.destroy()` on the component over using index of to remove it from the container.

Comment: There is an update to this answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165149/how-do-i-remove-a-component-dynamically-in-angular-9 which clarifies the correct way to call ```this.VCR.indexOf()``` as the code above would not work for me wtihout this update