# Rendering Angular components in Handsontable Cells

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, dynamic, handsontable

In a project of mine, I try to display Angular Components (like an Autocomplete Dropdown Search) in a table. Because of the requirements I have (like multi-selecting different cells with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click) I decided to give it a go with handsontable.

I've used the [handsontable renderer](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.18.0/demo-custom-renderers.html) and [add the components dynamically](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286).

The code looks like this

matrix.component.ts

```js
this.hot = new Handsontable(this.handsontable.nativeElement, {
  data: this.tableData,
  colWidths: [80, 300],
  colHeaders: ['Id', 'Custom Component'],
  columns: [
    {
      data: 'id',
    },
    {
      data: 'id',
      renderer: (instance: any, td: any, row: any, col: any, prop: any, value: any, cellProperties: any) => {
        if (cellProperties.hasOwnProperty('ref')) {
          (cellProperties.ref as ComponentRef<CellContainerComponent>).instance.value = row;
        } else {
          cellProperties.ref = this.loadComponentAtDom(
            CellContainerComponent,
            td,
            ((component: any) => {
              component.template = this.button4Matrix;
              component.value = row;
            }));
        }
        return td;
      },
      readOnly: true,
    },
  ],
});


private loadComponentAtDom<T>(component: Type<T>, dom: Element, onInit?: (component: T) => void): ComponentRef<T> {
  let componentRef;
  try {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], dom);
    onInit ? onInit(componentRef.instance) : console.log('no init');
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Unable to load component', component, 'at', dom);
    throw e;
  }
  return componentRef;
}
```

What's my current issue is the lifecycle of the rendered angular components.

Stuff I tried:

1. **Do nothing**

*Tried Solution*: Doing nothing and leaving everything to Angular

*Problem*: Angular never calling the ngOnDestroy of the CellContainer.

2. **Saving componentRefs**

*Tried Solution*: Saving the componentRef in an Array and after a certain amount of rendering trying to destroy the components I
rendered some time ago. Counting via time, handsontable hooks
(verticalScroll/beforeRender/afterRender), in the render-method

*Problem*: Destroy of the angular component always throws an error ('cannot read property'nativeNode' of null') or the components get
displayed completely wrong

3. **Check during rendering if an element is there**

*Tried Solution*: During the render: I checked if there's already a component and if it was I used to recycle the already-there component by adding a new value only.

*Problem*: The values get completely mixed up during scrolling.

A link to my solution (and an implemented solution #3) is available on [github](https://github.com/phhbr/handsontable-filled-with-ng-components).

Does anyone have an idea of how to handle this in a clean way? If not the application gets slow & unusable after a little bit of scrolling & using the table.
Better refer : https://handsontable.com/docs/8.2.0/tutorial-cell-function.html

Comment: I decided to go with ag-grid community edition instead of handsontable. The lifecycle of rendered cells is very easy to take care of there.. I also checked out ngx-datatable, but it does currently not support fixed columns which is one of the requirements of the project..

Comment: Is this answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44942210/2678218

Comment: There was a CSS issue occured when I try to integrate and this was fixed by this import in my common CSS

Comment: Can you fix the link to the repo?

Comment: hmm there exist angular integration for handsontable https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handsontable/angular did you try using it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a cell renderer.
Use the renderer name of your choice when configuring the column:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

const hot = new Handsontable(container,
 {
  data: someData,
  columns: 
[{
    renderer: 'numeric'
  }]

});
```

Answer (score -5):

may be you need to try changeDetection as below, forcing the new changes to your component.

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```