# How to remove component from view?

Tags: angular, angular5

I want dynamically remove components from my parent component.

```
<div>

 <my-component #component
    (remove)="onRemove(0)">
 </my-component>

 <my-component #component
    (remove)="onRemove(1)">
 </my-component>

 <my-component #component
    (remove)="onRemove(2)">
 </my-component>
</div>
```

child component emits to the parent, it works, in onRemove function:

```
constructor(private generalViewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {  
}

private onRemoveWidget(index:number) {

     this.generalViewContainerRef.remove(component);
}
```

but it's not working.

how can I do it?

Comment: Can you quantify not working? Do you get an error?  Or other behavior?

Comment: no error and no behavior, it happens nothing

Comment: if you want to remove dynamically check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939878/dynamically-adding-and-removing-components-in-angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove and add dynamically using `*ngIf`

HTML:

```
<div>
 <my-component *ngIf="showComponent">
 </my-component>
</div>
```

TS:

```
showComponent: boolean = false
```

Comment: thanks but I would prefer remove it, because it has some problems with drag and drop library

Comment: @cucuru It's not clear what you mean **remove it**, `*ngIf` does remove it from the DOM

Comment: hello @cucuru *ngIf will remove the dom from view