# Add component in table rows dynamically using ComponentFactory angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a component which have following html

> 

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<ng-container #container class="sample">

</ng-container>
 </tbody>
</table
```

And another component is having single tr(table rows)
i.e.

> 

```html
<tr>
 <input class="form-control form-control-text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter ID" [(ngModel)]="id"/>
</tr>
```

Now i am adding this table row component dynamically using this answer
[Dynamically ADDING and REMOVING Components in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939878/dynamically-adding-and-removing-components-in-angular)

But when it is rendered on browser i got following 
[Click on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SKmQ.png)

Dynamic component is rendered in a div but i just want tr inside tbody.

Please help.

UPDATE:i have created a dummy on stackblitz [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhewus)

Comment: a minimal stackblitz which recreates this issue will get you more help

Comment: Thanks Akber for suggestion , i have created stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhewus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes (screenshot below also)

1. In the **add-timeseries-row.component.ts** file, make change to the selector:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-timeseries-row',
  templateUrl: './add-timeseries-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-timeseries-row.component.css']
})
export class AddTimeseriesRowComponent {
 id1:string;
 id2:string;
 id3:string;
}
```

2. In **add-time-series.component.css** add this

```css
add-timeseries-row {
    display: contents;
}
```

[image: The 2 changes and their effect on the result...]

Comment: if you want the div, adding this in add-time-series.component.css would get the job done also... : .time-series-table-body > div { display: contents; }

Comment: Thanks a lot Akber,Now i am thinking how stupid i am ,i focused on angular but the solutions was only a css.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, this is where stackOverflow is so helpful... Lots of learning opportunities...