# How to Dynamically Remove component in ComponentResolveFactory

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am referring to this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-nxnqns) example to create forms dynamically and call them using componentFactoryResolver.
However, I also need a button to remove the added form.
Suppose user clicks on button then form is added and if he clicks again another form is added.So I need to provide a button to remove form.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

create a method like this

```
 removeComponent() {
    this.container.clear();
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
to remove an specific component use this:

First create a component array

```
  components = [];
```

then

```
   add(): void {

    // create the component factory
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);

    // add the component to the view
    const componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);

 this.components.push(componentRef );
    // pass some data to the component
    componentRef.instance.index = this._counter++;
  }


  removeComponent(componentIndex ) {

      // Remove component from both view and array
      this.container.remove(componentIndex );
       this.components.splice(componentIndex, 1);


  }
```

hope it helps

Comment: It removes all the component at one go... I want to be able to remove one by one ...suppose i click add component button 3 times then remove button should remove 1 form first then another and so on....

Answer (score 0):

I did a fork of your example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-stack-55683353?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I added a button with an output in the dynamic component to destroy it with this code:

```
componentRef.instance.onRemove.subscribe(() => {
  componentRef.destroy();
});
```

There is some examples on how to do it here too:
[Dynamically ADDING and REMOVING Components in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939878/dynamically-adding-and-removing-components-in-angular)