# How do I remove a component dynamically in angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to create a multi select filter that would accept multi option values to be clicked, in order to refine the response of some get API endpoint on the backend.

Whenever a user click on a option, a "chip" component would be dynamically render to aware the user: "hey you just filter the result by this, and that filter option"

Looking around in internet I found this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-or-remove-dynamic-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

In this code sample I understand that somehow in this lines:

```js
let componentFactory = this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
let childComponentRef = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

we insert an instance of a given child component inside a `ViewContainerRef`. find a object somewhat like this:

```
_data: Object { renderElement: <!--  -->, componentView: undefined, viewContainer: {…}, … }
_elDef: Object { nodeIndex: 4, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 1, … }
_embeddedViews: Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ] //here   
_view: Object { def: {…}, parent: {…}, state: 1036, … }
```

where under `__embeddedViews` object the dynamically generated views will be stack up

Later to decide which views will be deleted, the creator of this stackblitz just get the component and make a `ViewContainerRef.indexOf(component)` to get the index in which the component is stored and verify that that the dynamically generated component exist in that array. Then he/she just delete the view calling `this.ViewContainerRef.remove(index);`

Funny thing, in my implementation when I log my `ViewContainerRef` I get this object as response:

```
​_hostTNode: Object { type: 0, index: 23, injectorIndex: 34, … }
_hostView: Array(94) [ ..., {…}, 147, … ]
_lContainer: Array(12) [ <!--
```

The chips are successfully added dynamically as expected, but there is no _embeddedViews, so I cannot remove them dynamically because `ViewContainerRef.indexOf(chip)` will always return -1 as "no, I don't have a "chip" here"
Please can someone enlighten me and show what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I quickly took a look at all this, and whyu not just use a `ngFor` that render your chips depending on the user selected filter (that you probably store somewhere)? Your current approach sound so complicated for what you want to achieve

Comment: Wow, I have not tought it that way at all. It shows that im still strugling with angular lol. If you post this answer I will gladly tick as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: is not really an answer to your problem, so I don't think it s worth posting, is just a much simpler way to achieve the same result ^^
take a look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-list-of-items-yafewh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have such inconsistency because you're using ViewContainerRef API in a wrong way.

Here's the signature of [indexOf](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#indexOf) method:

```
abstract indexOf(viewRef: ViewRef): number;
```

This signature never changed during Angular updates.

The stackblitz you're referring to uses Angular 6 version that leverage ViewEngine under the hood but in your code you're using Angular 9 and above version where Ivy compiler comes into play.

In stackblitz you have:

```
this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef as any);
```

Meaning that you're passing ComponentRef instance not ViewRef instance. It works by accident because indexOf method looks like:

```
ViewContainerRef_.prototype.indexOf = function (viewRef) {
  return this._embeddedViews.indexOf(viewRef._view);
};
```

and

`ComponentRef._view === ViewRef._view` in `ViewEngine`.

**You should be passing `ViewRef` instance instead:**

```
this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef.hostView)
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-or-remove-dynamic-component-npaetz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)**

The demo works with Ivy(your particular case) but it will also work in ViewEngine.