# Angular - A function defined in one component, that generates dynamic child components can’t be called in a separate non related component

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, angular12, angular-dynamic-components

Update to this in [this new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987046/angular-dynamically-adding-removing-multiple-instances-of-a-single-component).

I have followed [this guide](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-or-remove-dynamic-component-npaetz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts) which I found by finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939878/dynamically-adding-and-removing-components-in-angular) but then being pointed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165149/how-do-i-remove-a-component-dynamically-in-angular-9) as a fix for some of the issues that occurred in the prior question. The first link code example allows me to dynamically add and remove multiple instances of a particular child component that appear within a parent component.

This works great and I’ve more or less copied the code in that example into mine with the only difference being that the examples ParentComponent I’ve called `LiveSummaryComponent` (which is a page) and the examples ChildComponent I’ve called `StatusBoxComponent`.

In the example code there is a button residing on the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent)` that calls the `createComponent()` when clicked, that deals with creating instances of the `ChildComponent (StatusBoxComponent)`. This works, however want I would like to do is to be able to have a button on a separate non related component to the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent)` that calls the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent) createComponent()` function instead. This separate component is actually a modal dialog pop up box, which I’ve named `AddStatusBoxComponent`.

In order to do this, I’ve copied how the example codes `ChildComponent (StatusBoxComponent)` does it, since this calls the `remove()` function that resides in the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent)` to remove an instance of itself (the ChildComponent (StatusBoxComponent)) from the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent)` page.

**My StatusBoxComponent is as follows:**

*html template:*

```
<button (click)="remove_me()">I am a Child {{unique_key}}, click to Remove</button>
```

*ts file:*

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { LiveSummaryComponent } from 'src/app/pages/live-summary/live-summary.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-status-box',
templateUrl: './status-box.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./status-box.component.css']
})

export class StatusBoxComponent implements OnInit
{
  public unique_key!: number;
  public parentRef!: LiveSummaryComponent;

  constructor() {}

  remove_me() 
  {
    console.log(this.unique_key)
    this.parentRef.remove(this.unique_key)
  }
}
```

**The ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent) is as follows:**

*html template:*

```
<button type="button" (click)="createComponent()">
   I am Parent, Click to create Child
</button>
<ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
```

*ts file:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ViewRef} from '@angular/core';
import { StatusBoxComponent } from '../../components/status-box/status-box.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-live-summary',
templateUrl: './live-summary.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./live-summary.component.css']
})

export class LiveSummaryComponent implements OnInit 
{
  @ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef })
  VCR!: ViewContainerRef;

  child_unique_key: number = 0;
  componentsReferences = Array<ComponentRef<StatusBoxComponent>>()

  createComponent() {
  let componentFactory =  this.CFR.resolveComponentFactory(StatusBoxComponent);

  let childComponentRef = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);

  let childComponent = childComponentRef.instance;
  childComponent.unique_key = ++this.child_unique_key;
  childComponent.parentRef = this;

  // add reference for newly created component
  this.componentsReferences.push(childComponentRef);
}

  remove(key: number) 
  {
    if (this.VCR.length < 1) return;

    let componentRef = this.componentsReferences.filter(
    x => x.instance.unique_key == key
    )[0];

    let vcrIndex: number = this.VCR.indexOf(componentRef.hostView);

     // removing component from container
    this.VCR.remove(vcrIndex);

    // removing component from the list
    this.componentsReferences = this.componentsReferences.filter(
    x => x.instance.unique_key !== key
    );
  }
}
```

In the `AddStatusBoxComponent` modal dialog I’ve followed the same pattern as to how the `ChildComponent (StatusBoxComponent)` calls the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent) remove()` function which definitely works. But when I attempt to execute calling the  `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent) remove()` function by submitting the button in the  `AddStatusBoxComponent` modal dialog I get the following error in the browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')
    at AddStatusBoxComponent.addStatusBox (add-status-box.component.ts:133:25)
    at AddStatusBoxComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_3_listener (add-status-box.component.html:4:54)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15285:1)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.js:15323:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39:1)
    at EventEmitter_.emit (core.js:25944:1)
```

**The AddStatusBoxComponent Modal Dialog code is as follows:**

*html template:*

```
<form [formGroup]="AddStatusBoxForm" (ngSubmit)='addStatusBox()'>
  <button class='green-button' type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Note, I’m hiding most of the other parts of the form for simplicity, but there is a reason I’m using the formGroup and ngSubmit for the button.

*ts file:*

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LiveSummaryComponent } from 'src/app/pages/live-summary/live-summary.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-status-box',
  templateUrl: './add-status-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-status-box.component.css']
})

export class AddStatusBoxComponent 
{
  public parentRef!: LiveSummaryComponent;

  constructor(private form: FormBuilder, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddStatusBoxComponent>) {}

  addStatusBox()
  {
    this.parentRef.createComponent();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Essentially I’m trying to create instances of `StatusBoxComponent` in a different unrelated modal dialog component that calls the `createComponent()` function that is defined in the `ParentComponent (LiveSummaryComponent)` but I can’t seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?, so everyone can get along with it.

Comment: So far, according to error log it's told `parentRef` in `AddStatusBoxComponent` is missing by somehow.

Comment: I've made some progress on this and have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879615/acessing-component-viewcontainerref-createcomponent-function-from-a-different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Acessing Component ViewContainerRef createComponent() function from a different non related component results in error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879615/acessing-component-viewcontainerref-createcomponent-function-from-a-different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Service` to achieve the communication of the event instead of trying to use the `createComponent` method that's inside the component directly.

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frkq8n) demo.

Note that this is in Angular v14, so I had to comment out a line regarding the dynamic component creation.

Also, I am not using an actual modal. But if you adjust the code, this should work in your case in exactly the same way.