# Acessing Component ViewContainerRef createComponent() function from a different non related component results in error

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular12, viewchild, angular-dynamic-components

[Link to updated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987046/angular-dynamically-adding-removing-multiple-instances-of-a-single-component).

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830955/angular-a-function-defined-in-one-component-that-generates-dynamic-child-comp) before. To briefly summarise; I’m trying to call a function that creates instances of a component using the **ComponentFactoryResolver** and **ViewContainerRef** inside of another function that is in a non related component. For specifics refer to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830955/angular-a-function-defined-in-one-component-that-generates-dynamic-child-comp).

However, since then I’ve made a bit of progress and have pinpointed the issue. I’ve changed the **AddStatusBoxComponent** ts file (the component I’m trying to call the other components function from) from this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LiveSummaryComponent } from 'src/app/pages/live-summary/live-summary.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-status-box',
  templateUrl: './add-status-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-status-box.component.css']
})

export class AddStatusBoxComponent 
{
  public parentRef!: LiveSummaryComponent;

  constructor(private form: FormBuilder, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddStatusBoxComponent>) {}

  addStatusBox()
  {
    this.parentRef.createComponent();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

to this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LiveSummaryComponent } from 'src/app/pages/live-summary/live-summary.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-status-box',
  templateUrl: './add-status-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-status-box.component.css']
})

export class AddStatusBoxComponent 
{
  //public parentRef!: LiveSummaryComponent;

  constructor(public parentRef: LiveSummaryComponent, private form: FormBuilder, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddStatusBoxComponent>) {}

  addStatusBox()
  {
    this.parentRef.createComponent();
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

where I’ve injected the **LiveSummaryComponent** into the constructor and added it to the providers in `app.module.ts` instead. With this I’m able to call the `LiveSummaryComponent createComponent()` function, and it works because I tested it by commenting out everything in that function and putting a simple `console.log()` to confirm it works.

However when I uncomment the normal contents of the `createComponent(`) function and call it from the **AddStatusBoxComponent** it now gives me a different error message in the browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')
    at LiveSummaryComponent.createComponent (live-summary.component.ts:52:38)
    at AddStatusBoxComponent.addStatusBox (add-status-box.component.ts:129:20)
    at AddStatusBoxComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_3_listener (add-status-box.component.html:4:54)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15285:1)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.js:15323:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122:1)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72:1)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49:1)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39:1)
```

This indicates that it’s line 52 in the **LiveSummaryComponent** which is this line that resides in the `createComponent()` function:

```
let childComponentRef = this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

this.VCR is a **ViewContainerRef**

that is defined as:

```
@ViewChild("viewContainerRef", { read: ViewContainerRef })
public VCR!: ViewContainerRef;
```

I’ve had to use **!** Else I get this error:

```
Property 'VCR' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

The `@ViewChild` I think comes from this in the **LiveSummaryComponent** template file:

```
<button type="button" (click)="createComponent()">
   I am Parent, Click to create Child
</button>
<ng-template #viewContainerRef></ng-template>
```

I know it might be confusing that both the `LiveSummaryComponent createComponent()` function has the same name as the `this.VCR.createComponent(componentFactory);` But they are different functions.

So I think the issue lies here, but I have no idea how to resolve it, so that I’m able to execute the `LiveSummaryComponent createComponent()` function inside the `AddStatusBoxComponent addStatusBox()` function at the click of a button.

The full code can be found in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830955/angular-a-function-defined-in-one-component-that-generates-dynamic-child-comp), with the only difference this time being my changes to how the **LiveSummaryComponent** is referenced in the **AddStatusBoxComponent** via dependency injection in the constructor.

I'm still new to Angular so  lot of this I don't really understand properly.

**Summary of what I want to achieve:**

What I'm trying to achieve is to create instances of a child component (**StatusBoxComponent**) within a parent (**LiveSummaryComponent**) but the function `createComponent()` that creates instances of **StatusBoxComponent** that resides in **LiveSummaryComponent** is called from a completely different component (**AddStatusBoxComponent**) which pops up as a modal dialogue when a button is pressed on a **HeaderCaomponent** But I can't access the **LiveSummaryComponent** `createComponent()` function from the **AddStatusBoxComponent** due the error I highlighted in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Service` to achieve the communication of the event instead of trying to use the `createComponent` method that's inside the component directly.

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frkq8n) demo.

Note that this is in Angular v14, so I had to comment out a line regarding the dynamic component creation.

Also, I am not using an actual modal. But if you adjust the code, this should work in your case in exactly the same way.

Comment: That worked nicely, i also tried it in the removeComponent function in a different component, although I couldn't figure out how to pass parameters to functions from different component via a service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a child component in a parent by taking an action; I would use a combination of ngif and maybe ngfor if you can add an infinite amount of children (like messages board or to-do lists).

Your createComponent function will only be a trigger for the component to display. Example:

ts:

```
this.displayPopUp = false;
// ...
constructChild = () => {
   this.displayPopUp = true;
}
```

html:

```
<button (click)="constructChild">click me</button>
<app-some-child *ngIf="displayPopUp"></app-some-child>
```

Is that what you try to achieve?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to create instances of a child component (StatusBoxComponent) within a parent (LiveSummaryComponent) but the function createComponent() that creates instances of StatusBoxComponent that resides in LiveSummaryComponent is called from a completely different component (AddStatusBoxComponent) which pops up as a modal dialogue when a button is pressed on a HeaderCaomponent But I can't access the LiveSummaryComponent createComponent() function from the AddStatusBoxComponent due the error I highlighted in the question

Comment: You do not need to access this function. You have to setup a service that shares some value between the component giving the order and the one receiving the order. Then react on the order being triggered.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, I have this: <div *ngIf="test?createStatusBoxComponent():false"></div> in the LiveSummaryComponennt html where test is either true or false. That I've just set in the same component for now.  When I set it to true it just creates instances of the StatusBoxCoomponent infinity and errors my program.

Comment: if you check my last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830955/angular-a-function-defined-in-one-component-that-generates-dynamic-child-comp it might give you give you a bit more idea of what I'm trying to do. I'm using the ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver and ViewContainerRef to dynamically add and remove multiple instances of a particular child component that appear within a parent component. I followed this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-or-remove-dynamic-component-npaetz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts,

Comment: I want to be able to do what the example code does, but create instances of those child components from a button click inside the separate modal dialogue component, instead of the button being in the same component, as where the createComponent() is defined.